# Is there a way to combine frequency and magnitude into a single variable?

Tags: correlation, frequency

I have some data where I observe something at a certain frequency each month. Each time I observe, I count a value of 1 if true or 0 if false. The data looks like this:

```
Date, freq, count_of_true
2021-12-01, 10, 4
2021-11-01, 20, 14
2021-10-01, 50, 30
```

I want to use the monthly count_of_true as an independent variable to check for correlation with a un-described dependent variable. But, count_of_true is a function of frequency (and other factors).

I could check correlation using a new variable: `true_rate = count_of_true / freq`. But true_rate does not take into account magnitude.

Is there a known way to create a variable that considers frequency and magnitude at the same time? For example, some popular formula which might use the Z-score of frequency variable as a weight which scales magnitude variable?

Comment: The questi9on is too abstract. With some context, maybe ...

Comment: by frequency, you mean the number of measurements?

Comment: @rep_ho yes number of measurements

Answer (score 1):

I think one way would assign a `Beta(count_of_true, count_of_false)`. I think that it would work because it get in account both the rate of trues as well the number of samples. And is possible to assess the confidence in those estimates. Another way would be use some kind of smoothing, for example:

https://lazyprogrammer.me/probability-smoothing-for-natural-language-processing/

Comment: I'll check out the link and get back. The function beta is really what I am asking for. Is there any well-known beta function?

Comment: The regular Beta distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

Comment: It looks like beta is a function of three parameters, 2 shape parameters and an $x \in {0, 1}$. Are you saying count_of_true and count_of_false are the shape parameters and $x$ would be the frequency?

Comment: The count of true and count of false are the shape parameters, and you will get a function of those two.  And with this function you can assess the shape, the width and another stuff from this curve. It won't be a single number, it will be a function which you can make inference.